# dismiss view controller that was present on storyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have 3 ViewController, `firstVC`, `secondVC` and `thirdVC`.

On `firstVC` I have a button with a `Present Modally` segue that presents `secondVC`.

On `secondVC` I have a button that presents `thirdVC`.

On `thirdVC` I have a button that should dismiss both VCs (`secondVC` and `thirdVC`).

**I've tried to do that like this:**

`NSNotificationCenter` post notification that calls this method on `secondVC`:

```
-(void)dismissCalendarView
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But It doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you please give me an Objective-C example?

Comment: Here is Objective-C
`[[self presentingViewController]presentingViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
`

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

if FirstVC is rootviewController..

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true];
```

if not,

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```